# Optimise a code of random number with no repetition in C

Tags: c, random

I do a code that will display to the screen 10 random numbers with no repetitions. I want to know if we can optimize the code or if you have a better and simple way in order to do this request.
Thanks !!

```
int main(){
int nbr = 0; srand(time(NULL));
int arr[10], i, j, flag;

for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    do
    {
        nbr = rand() % 10 + 1;
        flag = 1;
        for (j = 0; j  < i; j ++)
        {
            if (nbr == arr[j])
            {
                flag = 0;
                break;
            }
        }

    } while (!flag);
    arr[i] = nbr;
}

for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    printf("%5d", arr[i]);
}



system("PAUSE");
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please check in [codereview.se]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/36952047/971127

Answer (score 2):

So if i get what you're trying to do here it is:

generate an array of numbers between 1 and 10, in a random order  (given `rand() % 10 + 1`)

instead of trial and error I'd suggest the following algorithm:

- fill `arr` with 1...10
- shuffle `arr`

this will run a lot faster

Answer (score 1):

While I agree with the solution provided by Work of Artiz, this will result in the hard question to answer of *when to stop shuffling*.

To solve this you can use the following solution (which will use more memory, but less clock time):

**1** Create an array `temp` having values 1..10 (ordered, not random)

**2** Keep track of the length `length` of the array (10)

**3** Generate a random index `rand_i` between 0 and `length - 1`

**4** Copy `temp[rand_i]` to next position in your final array

**5** Overwrite `temp[rand_i]` by `temp[length-1]`

**6** Decrement `length`

**7** Iterate Steps 3 - 6 until your array is filled (10 times)

This will both eliminate your excessive looping, and the problem of when to stop shuffling your array

**EDIT**: including code

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(){
int nbr = 0; srand(time(NULL));
int arr[10], i, j, flag;
int temp[10] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
int length = 10;


for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{

        nbr = rand() % length;  // Generate random index between 0 and length - 1

       arr[i] = temp[nbr];      // Copy value from random index in temp to next index in arr

       // Now since temp[nbr] is already taken (copied to arr) we should replace it by last available value in temp (temp[lenght])
       // and in the next iteration we will create a value between 0 and length -1. This will keep values not yet taken from temp in 
       // contiguous order

        temp[nbr] = temp[length-1];
        length--;
}

for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    printf("%5d", arr[i]);
}



return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can I have a code, in order to understand more the process ?

Comment: I will work on it now. I did not have time before today. Will edtit and add it in the answer